# iOS - Google SignIn fails if a Google App is on the device

Tags: ios, google-signin

I've integrated Google SignIn (2.2) based on instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start

It works when there is no Google app on the device. So Google SDK opens a web view where I can sign in a google account, and GIDSignInDelegate method didSignInForUser is called with a valid access token with no error.

But if I have Google app or Youtube app installed, the SDK will open the Google app, where I can sign in my google account, and when I choose the account and it redirects back, it throws an error:

> "A potentially recoverable error occured. You may try again."

No matter how many times I retry it never worked.

(Deep link url: 
[com.googleusercontent.apps.<my app id>://api/sso/v1/tokenResponse?ec=-216414001&e=A%20potentially%20recoverable%20error%20occured.%20You%20may%20try%20again](http://com.googleusercontent.apps.<my%20app%20id>://api/sso/v1/tokenResponse?ec=-216414001&e=A%20potentially%20recoverable%20error%20occured.%20You%20may%20try%20again))

Has anyone seen the same issue? What could go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out to be a typo in the app bundle id in Google Developers Console.

As requested in some comments, here are some more details:
In order to support google sign in, you need to a client id in
https://console.developers.google.com
under APIs & Auth/Credential
In our case, we were seeing the error because in the client id we created for iOS app, we had a typo in the app bundle id. (Instead of com.companyname.appname we typed com.companyname.companyname)

I guess there can be other ways to cause the same error, but one good place to check is the developer console (https://console.developers.google.com), just make sure every field makes sense to you.

Comment: Having the same problem, can you be more specific with your answer please?  I can't figure out what you mean.

Comment: I'd also appreciate a little more info on this... Struggling with the error in PhoneGap Build on iOS (and presumably Android).

Comment: Hm my bundle id matches just fine but still seeing this error

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new Configuration file here -> https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.SignInExample&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fios%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Try%20Sign-In
- When it asks for your iOS Bundle Id, make sure it matches the bundle id that you find in your Xcode project settings (target -> General -> Bundle Identifier)
- Delete the old "GoogleService-Info.plist" file and replace it with the new one you just created
- clean, rebuild, try to sign in again